# My ImageView size has been changed

Tags: android

I've got a MainActivity, and I've got a custom TouchView object within the MainActivity which extends ImageView. No XML layout is used in my project, I have the following lines in the onCreate() of MainActivity:

```
 ...
    myTouchView = new TouchView();
    myTouchView.layout(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());//bitmap W*H: 3264*2448
    MainActivity.this.setContentView(myTouchView);
    ...
```

I then set a breakpoint in the onDraw() of TouchView and there I always get the width and height of TouchView object which are not 3264*2448 which I've set on layout(). This means the size of my TouchView has been changed before onDraw(). The width and height I got are 480*320(screen size in fact).

How can I get the correct `size(3264*2448)?`

Thanks!

Comment: see if you are intrested in xml it is much easier in xml

Comment: myTouchView = (TouchView)findViewById(...); But this object I get is not the one I need, because I wanna pass some values to the object in the constructor, yet this one can not get them.

Answer (score 0):

I've killed this question myself. I override onMeasure() like this:

```
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
 int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
 int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
 if(parentWidth == bmp.getWidth() && parentHeight == bmp.getHeight())
     super.onMeasure(idthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 else
     this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
 }
```

Works well for me, any potential bug.

Comment: Framelayout.LayoutParams params = new Framelayout.LayoutParams params = new Framelayout.LayoutParams(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight());
setContentView(myTouchView , params);

This works well too.